Hardhat unit test fails
trying to test the receive function in my smartcontract:
// Function to receive Ether. msg.data must be empty
    receive() external payable {
        if (msg.value < 0.001 ether) {
            revert InsufficientPurchaseAmount();
        }
        uint256 tokensToMint = (msg.value * TOKENS_PER_ETHER);
        if (totalSupply() + tokensToMint > MAX_SUPPLY) {
            revert MaxSupplyExceeded({
                requested: tokensToMint,
                max: MAX_SUPPLY
            });
        }
        _mint(msg.sender, tokensToMint);
    }

Deployment ran, and accounts are generated, other tests running. The block to test the function:
 it("Should receive Ether and mint tokens", async function () {
            const initialBalance = await hardhatToken.balanceOf(owner.address);
            const valueToSend = ethers.parseEther("1"); // Convert 1 Ether to Wei
            await owner.sendTransaction({ to: hardhatToken.address, value: valueToSend });
            const expectedMinted = 1000; // Assuming TOKENS_PER_ETHER is 1000
            const finalBalance = await hardhatToken.balanceOf(owner.address);
            expect(finalBalance).to.equal(initialBalance.add(expectedMinted));
        });

Error:
Token contract
       Transactions
         Should receive Ether and mint tokens:
     ProviderError: Contract creation without any data provided
      at EdrProviderWrapper.request (/Users/barnajanos/Documents/Module_1_sanctions/metanaHH/node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/hardhat-network/provider/provider.ts:430:19)
      at HardhatEthersSigner.sendTransaction (/Users/barnajanos/Documents/Module_1_sanctions/metanaHH/node_modules/@nomicfoundation/hardhat-ethers/src/signers.ts:125:18)
      at Context.<anonymous> (/Users/barnajanos/Documents/Module_1_sanctions/metanaHH/test/Lock.js:52:13)

verify deployment, test the function in remix.
